# Can multiple choices be triggered in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to trigger which would run all the choice params and it would be triggered at different time intervals.

```
Properties(
   Parameters{
    Choice(name: "Name", choices: 
    ["Option1", "Option2", 
      "Option3"].join('\n')
})
```

Can all the three options under choices be run at different time intervals?
If so, please let me know.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to run based on the Choice? What do you mean by "run all the choice params "?

Comment: Under choices I have included 3 options. I want to trigger option 1 at say 12:30 am and Option 2 at 6 am and Option 3 at 9 pm. Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 seperate Jobs for Option 1, 2 and 3 and then trigger them from the main Pipeline with a quiet period.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('TimerExample') { 
            steps{
                script {
                    def option1Time = secondsUntil hourOfDay: 0, minute: 30, second: 0
                    def option2Time = secondsUntil hourOfDay: 6, minute: 0, second: 0
                    def option3Time = secondsUntil hourOfDay: 21, minute: 0, second: 0
                    
                    echo "Option1 TIme: $option1Time "
                    
                    // Option 1 build
                    build job: 'Option1Job', quietPeriod: option1Time
                    
                    // Option 2 build
                    build job: 'Option2Job', quietPeriod: option2Time
                    
                    // Option 3 build
                    build job: 'Option3Job', quietPeriod: option3Time
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}

long secondsUntil(Map dateProperties ) {
    def now = new Date()
    def to = now.clone()
    to.set(dateProperties)
    long duration = groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus( to, now ).toMilliseconds() / 1000
    return duration > 0 ? duration : 0
}
```